How to convert sql `partition by` to criteria API query?
How to build complex queries using the criteria api? I tried to use the criteria api to implement the sql in the comment, but two days later the problem was not solved. I tried chatgpt, google, spring-data-jpa, hibernate documentation, and Jakarta ee documentation, but could not find similar code. Do these apis not support similar queries?
SQL to be implemented:
select test_version.*
from test_version
         join (select identification,
                      version,
                      dense_rank()
                      over (partition by identification order by major_version desc ,minor_version desc ,patch_version desc ) as rank
               from test_version) rk
              on test_version.identification = rk.identification
where test_version.version = rk.version
  and rk.rank = 1;

java code:
package com.example.addtionalcriteriademo;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Root;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Subquery;
import jakarta.persistence.metamodel.Attribute;
import jakarta.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.IdGeneratorType;
import org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MapAttributeImpl;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class AdditionalCriteriaDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdditionalCriteriaDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(TestVersionRepository repository) {
        return args -> {
            repository.findAll(repository.query()).forEach(System.out::println);
        };
    }

}

@Data
@MappedSuperclass
class AbstractVersion {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.AUTO
    )
    private int id;
    private String identification;
    private String version;
    private int majorVersion;
    private int minorVersion;
    private int patchVersion;
}

@Table
@Entity
class TestVersion extends AbstractVersion {
}

@NoRepositoryBean
interface AbstractVersionRepository<T extends AbstractVersion> extends JpaRepository<T, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {
    
    default Specification<T> query() {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            return null;
        };
    }
}

interface TestVersionRepository extends AbstractVersionRepository<TestVersion> {
}

the pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>additional-criteria-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>additional-criteria-demo</name>
    <description>additional-criteria-demo</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

please help.....

I created an AbstractVersionRepository because I wanted to provide version management functionality in an abstract interface, and its inherited classes can call methods of this class to stitch together their own queries (such as adding fuzzy queries or sorting rules for name or other fields, etc.)

You can't do over (partition by ...) with Criteria API. Why wouldn't you want to use native query?

@AndreySmelik  I try to use the criteria api because I want to provide a version query sql on the parent class interface, and the subclass can continue to add filtering conditions on the sql.

Unfortunately there are no "escape hatches" in those technologies. Hibernate had some in its criteria API (very limited) but it was removed in newest version (6).
The workaround is to use JdbcTemplate or NamedParameterJdbcTemplate when you need something non trivial from SQL database and you don't need conditional SQL generation (for this I recommend JOOQ or QueryDSL).

Thank you for your answer. I looked into the options you mentioned, but they don't quite fit my scenario. I'll have to downgrade to using native queries. Thanks again!

Does something like below will work for you? If not why?
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import java.util.List;

public interface TestVersionRepository extends JpaRepository<TestVersion, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT tv FROM TestVersion tv " +
           "WHERE tv.version = (SELECT max(tv2.version) FROM TestVersion tv2 " +
           "WHERE tv2.identification = tv.identification) " +
           "ORDER BY tv.identification, tv.majorVersion DESC, tv.minorVersion DESC, tv.patchVersion DESC")
    List<TestVersion> findLatestVersions();
}

